# Polynomial regression fitting curve with rrdtool graph

Tags: r, rrdtool

When using rrdtool graph, by default, a stepped line is created from the discrete samples, connected with vertical lines, e. g.:
[image: The rrdtool graph]

Using R, I would create a smooth, approximated curve from the samples like so:

```
y <- c(the data from the rrd)
x <- 1:length(y)
lo <- loess(y ~ x)
plot(x, y, ylim = c(-10, 10), col="gray")
lines(predict(lo))
```

The result looks like this:
[image: A R generated graph]

Can such a graph also be generated by rrdtool itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, rrdtool has no curve fitting abilities.

Comment: Thanks for the info! To jump at the chance when talking to the author himself: Do you plan to include such a functionality? R's loess function is imo something very desirable to have for a program like rrdtool, and the code is open source, and thus could probably be included or ported without too much effort (but I didn't have a look at neither R's code nor rrdtool's code). This would be very cool :-)

Comment: Not that easy after all … in R, it's not only C, the loess function seems to be partially implemented in Fortran. That's too much for me ;-) Would it be possible to do an "external" data processing? Like piping all values to an external program (shell script) and piping processed values back? This way, one could simply replace the data with the output of R's functions.

Comment: rrdtool allows you to write a callback function in perl that is responsible formfetching the data. you could use this to implement some fancy data massaging ...